# OpenGL - rotate player position to face mouse pointer

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, mouseevent, image-rotation

I'm new to OpenGL and C++ and I'm trying to develop a small game. The idea I'm trying to implement is a 2D shooter where the player faces the direction that your mouse is pointing. I've looked on the web for some help and examples but can't find much. Where do I start and has anyone got some good pseudo code to make this work? Thank you!

Comment: Is it a 2D shooter or 3D?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this. It's 2D

Comment: And what is blocking you from doing this ?

Comment: Not having enough understanding, I have a brief idea if someone could let me know if I'm on the right track....I have a vector for my player and then if I was to work out the coordinates of the current mouse position I could rotate the player by working out the angle between the mouse pointer coordinates and the player coordinates?

Comment: @P.Smith If you have the mouse position and player position (in the same coordinate system) then `mouse_position - player_position` is the "forward" vector you want for your player.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever API it is you're using to create the window/GL context will allow you handle events, namely mouse motion events so you can track the mouse's position **on screen coordinates**. Then you'll probably be using an orthographic projection and maybe your camera is not static and move along with the player.

Taking these variables into account here's a list of what you need.

1. First you need to get the mouse screen coordinates.
2. Convert them to world coordinates.
3. Calculate the vector from the player to this point.

---

**1 - For the first point**, for the sake of example, I'll use SDL since that's what I usually go with in my own projects. Otherwise I'll try to keep the code as general as possible.

```
...
while ( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) ) {
    if ( event.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION ) {
        mouseScreen.x = event.motion.x;
        mouseScreen.y = event.motion.y;
    }
}
...
```

**2 - For the second point** let's get some context and assumptions. Usually setting up your camera will look like this,

```
viewport( 0, screenWidth, 0, screenHeight );
...
ortho( projection, cameraLeft, cameraRight, cameraBottom, cameraTop )
translate( view, -cameraPosition )

//cameraWidth = cameraRight - cameraLeft;
```

In most 2D games your screen dimensions will be the same as the camera dimensions. If you change the camera dimensions it will look as though the camera is zooming in/out, so we'll take that into account.

Now let's assume the camera's origin is at the center of the screen. In which case your ortho function looks like this,

```
// halfCamWidth = cameraWidth/2;
// halfCamHeight = cameraHeight/2;
ortho( projection, -halfCamWidth, halfCamWidth, -halfCamHeight, halfCamHeight );
```

It could be the left-lower corner. But that depends entirely on how you decide to make your game. Using the lower left corner you can center the camera on a point (x,y) by doing,

```
cameraPosition.x = x - cameraWidth/2;
cameraPosition.y = y - cameraHeight/2;
```

Whereas if you use the center as the origin you would do

```
cameraPosition.x = x;
cameraPosition.y = y;
```

Which makes our calculations slightly easier. So if you use a different referential I'll leave that up to you.

**Back to the conversion,** we can now convert from screen coordinates to world coordinates in two steps. First we need to fit the mouse position within the camera projection. *(Beware of integer operations as you may have to cast dimensions to float)*

```
mouseWorld.x = cameraLeft + ( mouseScreen.x / screenWidth ) * cameraWidth;
mouseWorld.y = cameraBottom + ( mouseScreen.y / screenHeight ) * cameraHeight;
```

This formula gets us relevant values for x within `[-halfCameraWidth, halfCameraWidth]` and y within `[-halfCameraHeight, halfCameraHeight]`, basically within the ortho function's limits. Perhaps if the event handling can detect the mouse position outside of the window you'd get values outside of this interval, but that's not a problem for this formula.

Second we now need to place this point around the center of the camera,

```
mouseWorld.x = mouseWorld.x + cameraPosition.x;
mouseWorld.y = mouseWorld.y + cameraPosition.y;
```

And now we have the world position.

**3 - Finally, third point**, we calculate the vector from the player to this point.

```
Vector2 playerToMouseDirection = ( mouseWorld - player.position );
playerToMouseDirection.normalize();
```

**And that's it.**

If your player rotates instantly you're done. If you want your player to rotate more slowly you'll have to find a way to linearly interpolate the vectors (or the angles). Good luck.